# (bootstrap Jquery) Typeahead in multiple input field , how to find from where typeahead triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have two input fields and I want to use the same typeahead code in both the input control. The only difference is that the suggestion should come below that specific control.

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
   source: function (query, result){

       var data = 'data=' + query;
        if ((obj.user_latitude() !== 0) && (obj.user_longitude() !== 0)){
        
        data = data +"&radius=50000&location=" + obj.user_latitude() + "," + obj.user_longitude();
        }
        
        console.log(data);
       
       if (ajaxRequest) { // if any previous ajaxRequest is running, abort
          console.log("2");
          ajaxRequest.abort();
        }
        console.log("3");
       ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "/v1/Suggestions",
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            headers: {},
            success:  obj.addrSuggestion.bind(obj),
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("FAILED getSuggestions" + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
       
        });
}});
```

so in **success:  obj.addrSuggestion.bind(obj),** i want to pass the control details so that i can add condition to display it.